# Sharepoint 2013 Installation

Tags: installation

i wanna install sharepoint 2013 on windows server 2012 and i have some errors on prerequisetes for it!
here are some of these errors:

1. Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763): Installation skipped

2.Microsoft Identity Extensions: Installation skipped

3.Windows Server AppFabric: Installation skipped

Comment: Are these errors on very 1st time run or after couple of rebboots? Are their any other errors beside skipp?

Comment: they occured after couple of reboots

Comment: So what happen to installation?  Is it stopped with these errors or you just wondering about these?

Comment: it didn't stop but showed me these three installation after my installation complete

Comment: I think these are not errors rather information, during the installation server required reboot couple of time, so it just simply skipp the pre req which already installed. If installation successfully completed then no need to worry.

Comment: thank u so much but i ran some features that i googled them in my server manamement and i'm wating for windows serever running again (after restarting ) to find if them work correctly!! and i'll tell you the result